# How to bind the DataContext of the Window or its child to one specific property of the Window?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, datacontext

A bit silly question, but somehow I can't find how to bind the `DataContext` of the `Window` or its `Content` (e.g a `Grid` panel) to one specific property of the `Window` (say, `ViewModel` in my example below):

Code:

```
internal partial class MyWin : Window
{
    public MyViewModelType ViewModel { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="MyNs.MyWin"
        ...
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />

    <Grid DataContext={Binding ViewModel}> <!-- doesn't work??? -->
        ...
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Does `ViewModel` property raise `INPC.PropertyChanged` event? If not when do do you change it? Is it after `InitializeComponent()`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have this the wrong way around

if your window does the hooking up, it will work okay

```
public partial class MyWindow
{
    public MyWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = ViewModel = new MyViewModelType();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please define field for the viewmodel as it is not changing and implement INPC

```
 private MyViewModelType viewmodel;

    public MyViewModelType ViewModel
    {
        get 
        { 
            if(viewmodel == null)
            {
                viewmodel = new MyViewModelType();
            }
            return viewmodel; 
        }
        set 
        { 
            viewmodel = value; 
            OnPropertyChanged("ViewModel")
        }
    }
```

Rest of code remains the same.